# checking duplicate letter in string by converting to hashtable, KeyError

Tags: python

how can I get this code to return a non duplicate letter? It gives a KeyError instead

```
def nonDuplicate(string):

    hashTable = {}

    for i in string:
        if hashTable[i]:
            return i
        else:
            hashTable[i] = True

print(nonDuplicate('minimum'))
```

This should return 'n', however I keep getting a KeyError for the first element. What am I missing?

Comment: You're trying to access an element (`i`) before it's been assigned in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `i` is not in `hashTable`, you'll get a `KeyError`. It's not like in some other languages like JavaScript where you get `undefined` out, which is falsy (`Boolean(undefined) === false`).

Instead, you can check if `i` is in `hashTable`, since it doesn't really matter if it's `True`, as long as it's present.

```
if i in hashTable:
```

However, your code doesn't actually work. The output is `'i'`. You need to read the whole string to find non-duplicate characters. I recommend using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
def nonDuplicate(string):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(string)
    for x, count in c.items():
        if count == 1:
            return x

print(nonDuplicate('minimum'))  # -> n
```

Note: If you're using Python 3.6 or lower, this might return `'u'` instead of `'n'` since [dicts weren't necessarily order-preserving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get` instead, which will return `None` if the key does not exist (rather than raising a `KeyError`).

```
if hashTable.get(i):
```

To be explicit that the default value is `False`, you can pass a second argument (as suggested by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341)):

```
if hashTable.get(i, False):
```

Comment: `.get(i, False)` if you want to be really verbose

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyError` is caused by the if-statement because the first letter `'m'` is not in the dictionary, yet you are trying to retrieve its value. A correct approach would be to either call `hashTable.get(i)` or a more Pythonic way to check `if i in hashTable:`

Although this will solve the `KeyError`, I’m afraid it will not work correctly for finding the non-duplicate character. For that you will have to traverse the whole string and return the characters with exactly 1 occurrence.